# Android RadioGroup Radiobutton Java

Tags: java, android, radio-button

I have two radiogroups - RadioGroupSelect, questionRG. 
In RadioGroupSelect is radioButton1, radioButton2.
In questionRG is radiobutton questionRB1.
How to set any text in questionRB1 if i will select radioButton1 and set other text, if i will select radioButton2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code

```
    if(radioButton1.isChecked()){
        questionRB1.setText("your text");
    }
```

Do similarly for the other radio button.